# devstack - how to add directly attached storage to a single node installation

Tags: storage, cinder, devstack

I have devstack up and running on an Ubuntu 14.04 x86_64 VM in a single node environment.

The VM has / mounted on an 8GB primary disk and an 80GB secondary disk mounted on /mnt.

Output of mount

```
/dev/xvda1 on / type ext4 (rw)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /run/user type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=104857600,mode=0755)
none on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw)
/dev/xvdb on /mnt type ext3 (rw)
```

When nova starts up it only sees the primary disk as usable storage for VMs.

It doesn't recognize that it can use the 80Gb volume and I want it to.

I am new to Openstack/Devstack and I'm sure this is very easy, since I feel this has to be an extremely common use-case for people who just want to bring up a single node to develop against. I just don't know what commands to run or which config file to edit.

Devstack doesn't create a volume group call cinder-volumes by default, it creates one called stack-volumes. Someone else had me try this:

```
umount /mnt    # and remove it from /etc/fstab of course
pvcreate /dev/xvdb
vgextend stack-volumes /dev/xvdb
```

I restarted both nova & cinder in their respective screens, but I don't think anything has changed since Horizon sill shows 7Gb as the available provisioning space when I look at Hypervisors.

Does anyone know how this is done?

Internet searches seem to only point me to creating block storage for a specific instance and I don't care about that. I don't want to add volumes to instances. I want to add storage for provisioning instances to.

Many thanks.